# How to create a singleton observable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, singleton, observable, mobx

I have a singleton class :

```
let instance = null;
  class SingletonClass {
    constructor() {
      if (!instance) {
        instance = this;
      }
     return instance;
  }
  get types() {
    return this._types;
  }
  set types(value) {
    this._types = value;
  }
}
export default SingletonClass;
```

and i use it like this:

```
import SingletonViews from './SingletonClass';
export default class MyStore {
    this._singletonClass = new SingletonClass();
    @observable types;
    this.types= this._singletonClass.types; //i dont know what to do here to bind this two together
}
```

But whenever `this._singletonClass.types` updated the `types observable` wont. what can i do about it?
can i have a `@observable singleton` or can i bind its proprty to a `@observable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "singleton" is not an observable itself and what is your intention? just proxy the singleton values?

Since you don't seem to need to initialize your singleton, I'd rewrite it this way:

**Singleton**

```
import * as mobx from 'mobx'

const {observable, action} = mobx

class SingletonClass {
  @observable types

  @action setTypes (value) {
    this.types = value;
  }
}


export default new SingletonClass()
```

**MyStore**

```
import singletonClass from './SingletonClass'

export default class MyStore {
  singletonClass = singletonClass
}
```

Now you can use your store somewhere in your app and observe your singleton.